# Example of setting html text on button or next to radio/checkbox on form on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Can someone share an example of setting the html text on an button (or next to a radio button or checkbox) based on a value of a parameter from the URL (on page load preferably)?  I have found many ways to extract the parameter values and numerous examples of setting the value of a form control, but nothing to set the text on a button or next to a radio/checkbox.  The use case is that I want to build a dynamic choice of either redacted email or mobile number for password reset, and I am passing these parameters in through the URL.

Here is something similar I did with BUTTONS, but I want them to either be presented as radio buttons or checkboxes.

```js
const hash = '?uname=greg&email=greg%40blah.com&phone=7777777';
const example = "http://example.com/" + hash;

function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = example;
  var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
      return sParameterName[1];
    }
  }
}

var phone = GetURLParameter('phone');
var email1 = GetURLParameter('email');
var email2 = decodeURIComponent(email1);

document.getElementById('myButton').innerHTML = phone;
document.getElementById('myButton2').innerHTML = email2;
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="button" value=""></button>
<button id="myButton2" type="button" value=""></button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest you make an attempt, show us what you tried and where you get stuck. That gives us a better idea of your context and narrows the scope of the problem. For reference, see [this advice on how to improve your chances of getting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @showdev - added pseudo-example, would like to see something similar with radio buttons or checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for editing. Do you mean that each URL parameter would get its own radio button or checkbox? Like, one checkbox for the "email" value and one for the "phone" value?

Comment: @showdev - exactly!  Ideally, it would be radio buttons so they could only choose one, but it would work if it were checkboxes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a great start.
I've just modified your code to use checkboxes instead of buttons.

For each value, a label/radio pair is generated and added to the document body.

```js
const hash = '?uname=greg&email=greg%40blah.com&phone=7777777';
const example = "http://example.com/" + hash;

function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = example;
  var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
      return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
}

// build array of values
var values = [
  GetURLParameter('phone'),
  GetURLParameter('email')
];

// add a label/radio-button for each value
for (var k in values) {

  // create elements and text node
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  var radio = document.createElement('input');
  var text = document.createTextNode(values[k]);
  
  // set radio button properties
  radio.type = "radio";
  radio.name = "choose";
  radio.value = values[k];
  
  // if this is the first button, check it by default
  if (k == 0) {
    radio.checked = true;
  }
  
  // add the button and text node to the label
  label.appendChild(radio);
  label.appendChild(text);
  
  // add the elements to the document body
  document.body.appendChild(label);
  
};
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}

label input {
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you!  This is perfect.  I appreciate the help!